# Python 3 function import error

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to python please suggest me the solution

I have two python files first is `imtest.py` as follows:

```
d = dict()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    def salry(a):
        d["f"] = a

    print (d)
```

second is `testim.py` as follows:

```
import imtest 

a= 90
b = 200
imtest.salry(a)
imtest.salry(b)
```

When I am trying to run testim.py, it's giving error as :

```
AttributeError: module 'imtest' has no attribute 'salry'
```

Then I have modified second file `testim.py` as follows:

```
from imtest import salry

a= 90
b = 200
salry(a)
salry(b)
```

Now I am getting error as

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'salry'
```

What could be the error why I am not able to import that function?

Comment: salry is defined inside of the `if __name__ ...` scope, so it's not available.

Comment: Remove the `if __name__ == '__main__':` in `imtest` and define he function `salary` outside

Comment: You're putting the salry(a) inside the `if __name__=='__main__':` you can't import this function, this should be in the outer scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `__name__` magic variable has different value depending on whether the module is executed as a script (`python imtest.py`) or imported from another module. In the first case, `__name__` is set to `"__main__"`, in the second case it gets the module's name (`"imtest"` in your case). The result is that everything in the  `if __name__ == "__main__":` block is only executed when using imtest.py as a script. When you import it from testim.py this part is not executed, so the `def salry` statement is not executed, so the function is not defined, so you cannot import it.

The solution is quite obvious: put the function definition outside this block:

```
d = dict()

def salry(a):
    d["f"] = a

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print (d)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want your `salary` function to be available to other modules, it needs to be in outer scope, so:

```
d = dict()

def salry(a):
    d["f"] = a

    print (d)
```

Comment: ` print(d)` isn't part of the function, and you want to keep the main part too.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of this you have to this

```
d = dict()
def salry(a):
    d["f"] = a
    print(d)
```

now you can use it as 
`from imtest import salry`
Now it works fine

Answer (score -1):

Your imtest.py file is imported in your testim.py file, it's not the file that you're running. So it's not your main file, therefore the condition (**name** == '**main**') will be false, and the salry function won't be defined.

You must remove the if statement:

```
d = dict()
def salry(a):
    d["f"] = a
    print (d)
```